# How to embed python interpreter into an app written in Python?

Tags: python, interpreter

Maybe I am completely off track here (and above my paygrade for sure), but what I want to do is to give users of my app (That I am writing in Python since that's the language I know) a python interpreter to control some objects within my app. Something similar like many 3D and VFX softwares have (Maya, Blender, Nuke). This is the code I got so far:

```
#main.py
import code
import networkx as nx

class Env():
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = nx.graph.DiGraph()
        # load library with functions that will be availabel for user inside the app.
        import mylib
        functions = {f: getattr(mylib, f) for f in dir(mylib) if not f.startswith('__')}
        self._interpreter = code.InteractiveInterpreter(locals=functions)

    def execute_node(self, node=None):
        # In IRL the main object to be pass1ed to users' interpreter will be the self.graph object
        # but I made it more clear for this question.
        self._interpreter.locals['var'] = 42
        node = "print(var)\nprint(some_function())\nvar = 67" # Let's pretend node object contains this code.        
        self._interpreter.runcode(node)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = Env()
    # some code, node creation and so on...
    e.execute_code()
    print(e.locals['var'])
    


#mylib.py
var = None # I have to put this here because if there is no variable function fails at import
def some_function():
        print(var)
```

Output:

```
42 # This prints as expected
None # The print within the function prints the value that was there when module was initialized
67 # The last print returns expected value
```

So, it is clear that python interprets the functions on first import and "bakes" the global variables that it had at the import time. Now the question is can I somehow easily make it use the globals passed from the code.InteractiveInterpreter() or I should look for a completely different solution (and which one) :)? Of course the idea is that the two python programs should communicate, the user should use a special library to operate the software and the backend code should not be exposed to them. Do I make any sense? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one-ish instance where you do want to use the [`exec()` function](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#exec), but **please remember that the user may be able to run *any* Python code, including stuff that could run forever, mess up your main program, write (or delete) files, etc.**

```
def run_code(code, add_locals={}):
    code_locals = {}
    code_locals.update(add_locals)  # Copy in the additional locals so that dict could be reused
    exec(
      code, 
      {},  # no globals (you may wish to replace this),
      code_locals,
    )
    return code_locals  # return updated locals


class Beeper:  # define a toy object
    def beep(self, times):
        print("Beep! " * times)


beeper = Beeper()  # instantiate the object to play with

# Some user code...
user_code = """
x = 5
beeper.beep(x)
x += 3
"""

new_locals = run_code(user_code, {"beeper": beeper})
print(new_locals)
```

This outputs

```
Beep! Beep! Beep! Beep! Beep!
{'beeper': <__main__.Beeper>, 'x': 8}
```

So you can see we can use the locals the user has modified if need be.

Comment: I strongly agree with security concerns. If user code is ran at the same environment as app itself, it's just a time bomb before your app, credentials and source code are compromised. You might want to create isolated containers for user code execution and stream output to your app.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and prompt reply!! This solves the immediate question. I am aware of security, I should have said that this is for prototyping. But @go2nirvana you are right, I should probably find a different strategy altogather. Could you please, point me to some resources how would I go about to create isolated containers and stream data back and forth? Thanks again :)

Comment: @dzoniandric don't know if there is such article, but i'll try to give you a perspective on scope of work. You will need to host many docker containers with the same api running, or will have to create and run them dynamically, depending on your projects infrastructure. API will take requests with submitted code, run it and return output back. That's the concept. However, container isolation will have to be properly tested. API workload has to be tested too, to insure it can run multiple python processes at the same time, etc. I'd say, this is at least a month worth of work, most likely more.